# React: event handling in ES8

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use closest way of event handling in ES8 standards.  In React, what is the difference in:

```
  handleButtonPressSearch(inputValue) {
    this.setState({
      showAll: true
    });
  }
```

versus

```
  handleButtonPressSearch = (inputValue) => {
    this.setState({
      showAll: true
    });
  }
```

Which is the preferred way?

Comment: The first only works inside the "class" syntax. The second is an arrow function. Neither should be preferred as they are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should class methods be created with arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065425/should-class-methods-be-created-with-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 3):

> what is the difference in

Your first example is a *method*. When a method is called, `this` depends on *how* the method was called (as with traditional functions using the `function` keyword). So if you pass a reference to that method to other code as a callback (for instance, an event handler), you need to ensure `this` is set to your component instance, not to something else.

Typically when you use methods, in the constructor you bind them to the instance:

```
this.handleButtonPressSearch = this.handleButtonPressSearch.bind(this);
```

Your second example is using [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) syntax and an arrow function. Arrow functions don't care what `this` you call them with, they ignore it; instead, they use the `this` that was in context where they were created. For a class field, that's the instance. Consequently, you don't need that `bind` call; `this` within that function will always refer to your component instance.

Note that class fields syntax still isn't standard JavaScript, [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is at Stage 3, though, and most React projects are set up to let you use class fields via transpilation.

> Which is the preferred way?

Neither is preferred, it's a matter of style. Both have access to the instance, and both can use `super` if necessary (though in React, inheritance is usually discouraged).